# Using htaccess to change document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My website has document root ~/public_html but i want to add all the files into ~/public_html/www

Is there a way to do this with htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: It is on of the common doubts. Some users are always keen on closing questions. will they get points out of it?

Comment: A similar question was asked here, and thankfully has not been closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost

Answer (score 52, accepted):

add the following lines to the .htaccess file in the public_html folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of the 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]' and the 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$'? I am using it without those two lines and it seems to be working...

Comment: This makes the condition pattern case insensitive, no difference between 'A-Z' and 'a-z'.

Comment: Isn't it possible setting the document root in the htaccess file as in the httpd.conf file, with something like `DocumentRoot "c:/inetpub/wwwroot"`?

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande I don't believe you can set `DocumentRoot` inside `.htaccess`, only within `httpd.conf`.