# .htaccess rewriterule to path outside wwwroot

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the document root of my web folder. I don't have access to the httpd.conf or the virtual host definition so I can't change it there.

I saw this question: [Using htaccess to change document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118941/using-htaccess-to-change-document-root) and know you can use to rewrite the incoming URL to a new path.

The document root is on this path: `/httpdocs/*`
And I want it to rewrite everything to `/subdomains/new/httpdocs/*`

If I look at the 'normal' rewrite rule it rewrites to a relative path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$

RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

How is it possible to rewrite outside the wwwroot?

Comment: You can jump down the folder tree, but not up (outside of existing website root). It's a basic security restriction, otherwise you (or hacker) will easily be able to get anywhere on the file system. The only thing you can do here (without changing actual website root), is to redirect all such requests to some php (or whatever) file, that (if have enough access rights) will do the rest (read files outside the website root and serve it back) -- not ideal and definitely slower.

Comment: ... Not to mention a security hole.