# How to set document root to be a subdirectory using .htaccess and not VHost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vhosts

On my local machine the following works perfect:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
       ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/website_1"
       ServerName testpage.com/website_1
       ##ServerAlias www.recruitement.localhost
       ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
       ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Howerver Im hosting my website to hosting company called **justhost.com** and they do not allow me to modify **httpd-vhosts.conf** or **httpd.conf**. Now my entire site is coded so that files under website_1 reference to other files under website_1 using simple slash "/" meaning website_1 is treated as document root. This works perfectly on local machine but when uploaded to host it gives me server errors because cant find the files since its trying to locate those files in **public_html**

For example:

```
  public_html
      - website_1
         - script.php
         - style.css
```

inside my **script.php**:

```
<a href="/style.css">See My Style</a>
```

this works good on local machine but on host it fails since it tries to locate style.css under **public_html** and not **public_html/website_1**

Is there a way to have multiple document roots without using VHosts? Like using .htaccess or something else. Please I want to try to avoid rewriting the code as much as possible since its around 10 thousands lines of code.

Comment: What about `__DIR__` or have you tried `./` ?

Comment: I dont want to use ./ nor __DIR__ that will require restructuring of thousands of lines of code

Comment: I completely fail to see your problem. There's nothing in your vhost definition that's even remotely weird, or would require a bunch of `.htaccess` rules. Just upload the website_1 folder directly to public_html at your hoster and it should work fine.

Comment: but I wont be able to use <img src="/img_1.png" /> since it would look for img_1 under root folder which is public_html

Comment: Not if, as I suggest, you upload the `website_1` contents directly to `public_html`, then the image will resolve fine. On a shared hosting environment you'll have to live with some predefined universal facts, such as that the `DocumentRoot` is fixed to the `public_html` folder on DirectAdmin servers.

Comment: base has to be included in each page. I dont have HTML parts in all pages so i cant put <head></head> in each page

Comment: [Changing the root folder via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess)

Answer (score 18):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website_1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website_1/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/website_1/$1 -l
RewriteRule (?!^website_1/)^(.*)$ /website_1/$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I dont have access to httpd.conf since its hosting company not dedicated server.

Comment: do i need to replace DOCUMENT_ROOT with something?

Comment: I get redirect loop. Where do I put the .htaccess under public_html or under public_html/website_1?

Comment: As I already mentioned above code will go under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`. About redirect look may I know what URI did you try?

Comment: it adds this code to htaccess instead of your first line of code: 
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews

Answer (score 7):

Make a entry in a .htaccess. Suppose you have a website abc.com. You want to run another website in directory. Then create a .htaccess in parent directory pointed to abc.com

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory/

RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That works like a charm for Ignition-Go (CodeIgniter project)

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting all image requests to root could be a solution. You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check if request is for an image at root. Add/remove file types if necessary.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif|css) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/website_1  [NC]
# Rewrite request to point to "website_1" directory
RewriteRule .*               /website_1/%1.%2          [L,NC]
```

Comment: well image is an example it might be different files. All files under website_1 has to have document root at /website_1

Comment: Yes, it will map all images files regardless of their name as long as the extension is in the condition. No, `/website_1` is not the root directory at `justhost.com`. It is `public_html` according to your question and I assume `/website_1` is a directory under it. But, have you tried the code in the answer and if so, what's the error or problem?

Comment: Image was just an example. If i have a index.php and style.css under public_html/website_1/ I need to reference to style.css from index.php using just /style.css and not /website_1/style.css. The above code gives me 500 internal server error

Comment: Modified my answer adding the `.css` file type and one condition to prevent loops (500 error).

Comment: can you make it so if it was requested any file under website_1 it loads them from website_1/ ? not only images and css it could be php, js etc

Comment: it gives me 500 internal server error. nothing in error_logs it says this: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Any file in other words, which means redirecting the whole root to /website_1 or are there exceptions?

Comment: exceptions are that there might be files under public_html that reference files under public_html those files should load other files from public_html. Basically only the files that are under website_1 should have document root website_1 and not public_html

Answer (score 2):

This question maybe old, but I have tried and this code works:

```rb
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Environment Variables

    ## For example a laravel app
    ## Document : D:/xampp/htdocs/web/app/laravel/.htaccess
    ## Path     : D:/xampp/htdocs/web/app/laravel/public/index.php
    ## URI      :                /web/app/laravel/public/index.php
    ## root_path   = web/app/laravel
    ## public_path = public
    ## app_file    = index.php

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^.* root_path=web/app/laravel
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^.* public_path=public
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^.* app_file=index.php

    # Make folder to be not indexable
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Protect hidden files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!(^|/)\.well-known/([^./]+./?)+$" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    DirectoryIndex %{ENV:app_file}

    # Serve Public Files
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:root_path}/%{ENV:public_path}/$0 -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:root_path}/%{ENV:public_path}/$0 -f
    RewriteRule ^.* %{ENV:public_path}/$0 [END]

    # Reroutes to app preprocessor (like index.php or index.html)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:root_path}/%{ENV:public_path}/$0 !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:root_path}/%{ENV:public_path}/$0 !-f
    RewriteRule ^.* %{ENV:public_path}/%{ENV:app_file} [END]

</IfModule>
```

You may like to read the documentation, here all resources I used:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/quickreference.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html

You may also like to see `error.log` in LogLevel Debug to see what's wrong with the script if it is not works.