# Use htaccess to redirect root to subfolder without showing it in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I am currently hosting a website using the [Silex framework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) on a shared server and I have a problem...

Silex is like Symfony, there is an app.php file located in a /web/ subfolder : the website is then only accessible via the URL website.com/web/. I cannot create a virtual host as it is a shared server, so I think the solution is to use an .htaccess file...

I managed to redirect website.com to website.com/web/ automatically but I don't really like this option. I would rather website.com pointed directly to website.com/web/ but I don't know how to do this by just using a .htaccess file. I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now and it's killing me...

At the moment I use this file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

but it just redirects you from website.com to website.com/web

Is there anyway I can make the root url directly point to the /web folder with a .htaccess file?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Maybe this could help you, might even be a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost

Comment: I guess you do not want to change `DocumentRoot` in your existing `VirtualHost` configuration?

Comment: Yes I don't have access to the VirtualHost configuration as it's a shared hosting :(
The topic is indeed very interesting, i'll look into it!

Answer (score 6):

If you want access to http://example.com/subdirectory just by typing http://example.com this should work.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 

RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/ [L]
```

Comment: works, but seems to make example.com/subdirectory/something out of example.com/something . Which is intedned in reality, but should be hidden in the url..

Answer (score 1):

Try this htaccess configuration:

```
DirectoryIndex web/app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /web/app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```