# How do I change the default link structure in Apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, server

I recently made my own LAMP-stack server for the first time, and I have a question regarding the link-building on my multiple domains.

I have a single IP with about 30 domains, in its own folders. What I want to do, is to link the "root" to the root of the folder only. An example:

```
<img src="/logo.png"> in the file: 111.22.333.44/domain.com/testfolder/index.php
should show: 111.22.333.44/domain.com/logo.png instead of: 111.22.333.44/logo.png
```

How do I change this? I tried installing ISPConfig to make the domain folders, but it wont work anyway.

I am running Ubuntu with PHP5 and Apache2.

Comment: I found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512881/how-to-set-document-root-to-be-a-subdirectory-using-htaccess-and-not-vhost], which is about the same, but I want to have a default installation, that will work on all the domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide additional port for each of your site (if you don't have domains that point to your server). For example, `111.22.333.44:6000` for `site_a`, `111.22.333.44:6001` for `site_b`. Edit your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and make Apache to listen to ports

```
Listen 6000
Listen 6001
Listen 6002
...
```

Make sure your `VirtualHosts` respond to the respective ports and provide your `DocumentRoot` for each site

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.333.44:6000>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/site/document/dir
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache and you can access the file

```
111.22.333.44:6000/logo.png
```

Comment: I do have domains, but I can use the DocumentRoot for the VirtualHosts - thank you!